# Yarn cache clean freezes and gets killed?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

```
> yarn cache clean --verbose
yarn cache v1.22.5
verbose 0.214901496 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/foo/.npmrc".
verbose 0.215859508 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/share/.npmrc".
verbose 0.216425682 Checking for configuration file "/usr/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.216821742 Checking for configuration file "/root/.npmrc".
verbose 0.217187573 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/foo/.npmrc".
verbose 0.217560011 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/.npmrc".
verbose 0.217940733 Checking for configuration file "/var/.npmrc".
verbose 0.219165411 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/foo/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.219591156 Checking for configuration file "/usr/local/share/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.219950712 Found configuration file "/usr/local/share/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.220435373 Checking for configuration file "/usr/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.220739566 Checking for configuration file "/root/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.220987407 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/foo/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.221319386 Checking for configuration file "/var/www/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.221648362 Checking for configuration file "/var/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.235171599 current time: 2021-06-25T02:44:12.673Z
⠁ Killed
```

It gets stuck on "current time" for about 10min, then it gets killed. What's going on here?

The cache directory was `/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6`, removing this didn't fix the error.

Comment: I'd move it or rename it ... if things go belly up, move/rename it back :p

Comment: I moved it and it still freezes :(

Comment: well, it's nothing to do with `/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6` then - not sure why you think that folder is at all relevant - it's never output